# Unable to get fcm notification when app is in background

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send a notification to group of devices, but some devices receive it and some do not. I am unable to get FCM notification when my app is in background. I searched but could not solve my issue.

This is my service class:

```
public class FCMCallbackService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
    NotificationsSqlLiteOperations  notification_db_class ;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    int sum=0;
    Context context;
    int notice_count,meetings_count,issue_count,assets_count ;
    SharedPreferences sharedPref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    int count;
    String image;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
    {


        Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {

            Log.e(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }

        try {
             sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            editor = sharedPref.edit();

            JSONObject a = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData());

            String notif = a.getString("data");
            Log.e("check notif",notif);

            JSONObject data = new JSONObject(notif);
            String type= data.getString("type");
            Log.e("check of type",type);

            count  = sharedPref.getInt(type, 0);
            count++;
            Log.e("count is",count+"");
            editor.putInt(type,count);
            editor.commit();


            if(  a.has("image") )
            image = a.getString("image");


            sendNotification(notif);

        }catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e(TAG,e.getMessage());
        }
    }

 private void sendNotification( String messageBody )
    {
        try {

            Bitmap   bitmap1,logo;
            JSONObject b = new JSONObject(messageBody);

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashScreen.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle("Society Snap")
                    .setContentText(b.getString("message"))
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            if( b.has("logo") ) {

               logo = getBitmapfromUrl(b.getString("logo"));
                notificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(logo);
            }


            if( b.has("image") ) {

                bitmap1 = getBitmapfromUrl(b.getString("image"));


                notificationBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                        .bigPicture(bitmap1).setSummaryText(b.getString("message")));
            }


            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
                int color = 0x008000;
                notificationBuilder.setColor(color);
                notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_society);
            }else{
                notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_society);
            }


//            FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;
//            mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
//            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
//            bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, "1");
//            bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, messageBody);
//            mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);

//            Log.e(TAG,messageBody);
//            Context context = this;
//            sharedPref = PreferenceManageRr.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
//            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
//            editor.putString("count", messageBody);
//            editor.commit();


//        @android:drawable/ic_delete

            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e(TAG,"send notif"+e.getMessage());
        }




//        try
//        {
//            JSONObject jsonObject =new JSONObject()
//
//            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashScreen.class);
//            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
//            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
//                    PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
//
//            Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
//            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
//                    .setContentTitle("SocietySnap")
//                    .setContentText(messageBody)
//                    .setAutoCancel(true)
//                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
//                    .setLargeIcon(image)
//                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
//                            .bigPicture(image).setSummaryText("message"))
//                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
//            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
//                int color = 0x008000;
//                notificationBuilder.setColor(color);
//                notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_society);
//            }else{
//                notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_society);
//            }
//
////            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
//
//            NotificationManager notificationManager =
//                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
//
//            notificationManager.notify(77/* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
//
//        } catch (Exception e) {
//
//            Log.e(TAG,e.getMessage());
//        }
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmapfromUrl(String imageUrl) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle notification when app in background in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase)

Answer (score 0):

Firebase notifications are of two types.

Check this link to get more information about firebase notifications.

[How to handle notification when app in background in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase/38795553)

Comment: i have done all this , like writing a services in manifest and  "data" is used as in api call

Comment: but nothing works, i'll get notification when app is foreground